# C#/Razor If referrer equals or contains

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to figure out what the best way, in C#, to get the referrer URL and if it contains or equals a certain URL.

The code:

```
Uri referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;

<p>URI referrer is: @referrer</p>
<p>Full page URL is: @fullUrl</p>


if (referrer != null && referrer.Contains("mysite.com")) // this doesn't work - referrer doesn't have .Contains()
{
  <p>Allowed</p>
} else {
  <p>Not Allowed</p>
}
```

Any ideas on how that would work to see if a referrer contains or is equal a certain string or URL?

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8#properties

Answer (score 1):

`Uri` [is an object and not an string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1), so you cannot use `.Contains()` with it.

An approach would be to extract the host from the `Uri` object and then (as it is a String), perform your check with `Contains()` ([there are more properties you could use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1#properties)).

Example code:

```
Uri referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer;

<p>URI referrer is: @referrer</p>
<p>Full page URL is: @fullUrl</p>


if (referrer != null && referrer.Host.Contains("mysite.com")) // Host is a string and has the Contains method
{
  <p>Allowed</p>
} else {
  <p>Not Allowed</p>
}
```

Example Fiddle: [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UjhFI1).

Please note that checking the referrer could not be the best solution for your problem, as it can be modified. Please check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer).

Also, take into account that `Contains()` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `referrer.Host`. However I'm not sure using this approach in the razor is the best solution or not. May be using an implementation in a base controller would be better.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer?view=netframework-4.8) returns an object of type URI.
if you need to access the whole url as a string u can use the [AbsoluteUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.absoluteuri?view=netframework-4.8) on this object.

Please note that string.Contains is case sensitive